# GPS Application crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

I have to write an application which does several things, including recording the GPS location of the user when a correct username and password is entered. I only want the latitude and longitude at that exact moment, no recurring checks or anything of that nature. I think I found something similar to what I was looking for:

[How to call to get a single gps fix when ever i want android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618263/how-to-call-to-get-a-single-gps-fix-when-ever-i-want-android)

However, eclipse didn't like the context since I hadn't initialized it yet. So here is that entire section of the code:

```
Context context = getBaseContext();
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Location Manager called");
Location loc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Last known location received");
Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Latitude:"+latitude);
Double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Longitude:"+longitude);
Toast.makeText(context, latitude+","+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And for permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.foxcatch.code.insecure.LOCATION_FINDER" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

However this crashes when I try to access the latitude and longitude and assign them to doubles:

```
Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
Double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
```

Here's the LogCat Error entry, its a little over my head:

> 04-28 18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-28 18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548): Process:
>   com.rps.personaldata, PID: 32548 04-28 18:00:39.346:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32548): java.lang.NullPointerException 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   com.rps.personaldata.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
>   04-28 18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445) 04-28 18:00:39.346:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32548):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18429) 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-28 18:00:39.346:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32548):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081) 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-28 18:00:39.346:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32548):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
>   04-28 18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 04-28
>   18:00:39.346: E/AndroidRuntime(32548):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I'm new to android, and I'm just trying to figure all of this out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I also tried initializing the context with getApplicationContext(). It too seemed to crash on the same line.

Comment: As the stack trace says, the problem is `at com.rps.personaldata.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)`.  Which line is that?

Comment: Line 58 is this line:
Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();

Comment: Evidently `loc` is null.  The docs explain why that may happen.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

Why getting the BaseContext.. just simply call directly the `getSystemService`

**change this:**

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

**to:**

LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It crashed in the same place, on line 58, where I call Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();.

Answer (score 0):

`locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` is returning `null`, which is why you're getting the NullPointerException.  Any `Context` should work in retrieving the `LocationManager`.

`getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` may return `null` if GPS hasn't been used in the recent past (especially since last reboot).

If a slightly less accurate location (e.g., cell tower level) is acceptable for your application, a better approach is to loop through all LocationProviders and find a non-null location:

```
public static Location getLocation2(Context cxt) {
    LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) cxt.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mgr.getProviders(true);
    Location last = null;
    for (Iterator<String> i = providers.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Location loc = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(i.next());
        // If this provider has a last location, and either:
        // 1. We don't have a last location,
        // 2. Our last location is older than this location.
        if (loc != null && (last == null || loc.getTime() > last.getTime())) {
            last = loc;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

This will use give you the last known GPS position if it is available, and if not, you'll likely get a NETWORK_PROVIDER position.

Note that in rare cases (on normal Android devices) all providers may return `null`.  In this scenario, you'd need to register a [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and wait for a new location to be provided.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23224818/937715 for a full solution.

Related - for code that takes into consideration the accuracy of each position from each provider, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364664/937715.

One final note - you may want to consider using the new(er) [fused location provider](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) that is part of Google Play Services, which in my experience is better about always providing a last known location.  For sample code that gets the last known location using the fused location provider, see the ["Retrieving the Current Location" example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).